# Can I invoke rails runner from arbitrary directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, integration-testing, whenever

I am writing some integration tests for a Rails application.  The application has a set of background tasks which are normally scheduled via `cron`/`whenever`. Since the `cron` jobs only run every few hours, I want to run them directly from the integration tests rather than wait for the `cron` jobs.

Each task is invoked by `whenever` using:

`runner "<module>.<task>"`

i.e. using the rails runner.

My integration tests live in the API wrapper around the application, which is in a different directory to the Rails application.

The question therefore is, can I invoke `rails runner` on a different directory from the current one, or invoke code in the Rails environment from within an rspec example outside of the Rails project?

Just running `rails runner xxx` doesn't seem to work (just prints the usage banner) from anywhere other than the top level of the Rails app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
<your-app-root>/script/rails runner <arguments>
```

where `<your-app-root>` is the root path of your application and `<arguments>` are the arguments you would give to the runner anyway.